# How to make a dropdown in Tablayout in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have a tab layout which contains three tabs with a different fragment.What I want to add a dropdown to tab 0. How do I do that

code:-

```
 mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
 mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
 mTabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj6Zq.png)

Comment: Unclear ! And also the image you have attached doesn't show anything . be more specific with your question .

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

//Java code

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.spinner));

mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setView(layout);
```